# How to apply log scaling to matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a latitude/longitude plot, with a c value "myValue". I need to apply a scaling to the c value because at the moment all the points are coming out with a similar color. I'm thinking log scaling would do the trick. How can I do this, such that the the color of the points are scaled, and the correct values on the c-bar are also presented?

```
df.plot(kind="scatter", x="Longitude", y="Latitude",
c="MyValue", cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"),
colorbar=True, alpha=0.4, figsize=(20,14) 
)
```

Comment: Use a `LogNorm()`

Comment: Yes, thanks, how do I use this in the above code?

Comment: Doesn't `matplotlib` scale the color automatically? Can you give an example of your data and outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see it works for you

```
df.scatter(x="Longitude", y="Latitude", c="MyValue", cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"), colorbar=True, alpha=0.4, figsize=20,14) ))
df.set_yscale('log')
df.set_xscale('log')
```